# Как сделать подсветку области списка под конкретный пункт?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть список с вложенным в него подсписком. Интересует как с помощью стилей сделать так, чтобы при наведении на **только пункт меню с подсписком** область подсвечивалась в желтый цвет - **именно вся область вместе с самим пунктом!** 
Код и [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/s93bnbh1/3/)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.main:hover li.second.current,
ul.main:hover ul {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.second {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
.second.current {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li class="second current">Пункт 1
  <ul>
    <li>Подпункт 1</li>
    <li>Подпункт 2</li>
    <li>Подпункт 3</li>
  </ul></li>
  <li class="second">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="second">Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Сейчас при наведении на любой пункт списка область подсвечивается, а нужно только под конкретный пункт

Comment: А что вы хотите получить то? Удалите во втором свойстве `ul.main:hover ul`, оно же?

Comment: @borodatych и что в итоге получится? точно не ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде, то что нужно:

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
li.second.current:hover, 
li.second.current:hover + ul
{ background-color: yellow; color: black }
.second {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#000;
  color:white;
}
.second.current {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
<li class="second current">
  Пункт 1
</li>
<ul class="hovered">
   <li>Подпункт 1</li>
   <li>Подпункт 2</li>
   <li>Подпункт 3</li>
  </ul>
<li class="second">Пункт 2</li>
<li class="second">Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: что то не работает, не удовлетворяет условиям автора, мой код тоже самое делал. только без изменения DOM дерева

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял то:

Это:

```
ul.main:hover li.second.current,
ul.main:hover ul {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Поменяй на это. При наведении только на пункт, будет подсвечиваться внутренняя область блока `li`, а наведя на под список свечение пропадет

```
li.second.current:hover + ul {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

---

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li.second.current:hover + ul {
  background-color:yellow;
}
.second {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
.second.current {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
<li class="second current">Пункт 1</li>
  <ul>
  <li>Подпункт 1</li>
  <li>Подпункт 2</li>
  <li>Подпункт 3</li>
  </ul>
<li class="second">Пункт 2</li>
<li class="second">Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Либо так, если нужно выбирать все:

**Изменено так:**

```
li.second.current:hover + ul, ul.hovered:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
li.second.current:hover + ul, ul.hovered:hover { background-color: yellow; }
.second {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#000;
  color:white;
}
.second.current {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
<li class="second current">
  Пункт 1
</li>
<ul class="hovered">
   <li>Подпункт 1</li>
   <li>Подпункт 2</li>
   <li>Подпункт 3</li>
  </ul>
<li class="second">Пункт 2</li>
<li class="second">Пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38803/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум у вас не правильная разметка. Дочернее ul li не лежит внутри родительского li.

Немного изменил разметку ([фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/s93bnbh1/2/)):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li.second.current:hover, li.second.current:hover span {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.second span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

.second.current > span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
  <li class="second current">
    <span>Пункт 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="second"><span>Пункт 2</span></li>
  <li class="second"><span>Пункт 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Дак, в комментарии в первом ответе отметили уже...

Comment: @dluhhbiu а без `span` никак? я просил в вопросе стилями.. т.е. без правки `html` и без скриптов

Comment: @borodatych простите- а что ответили?